# Executing cmd commands in Windows from PHP Issue

Tags: php, windows, command-line

Is it possible to execute cmd commands in Windows OS with PHP exec() function?

I tried this:

```
<?php

try {

    echo exec(
    'O:\test\pdftk.exe O:\test\outputs\OPP\out.pdf O:\test\outputs\OPP\out2.pdf cat output O:\test\123.pdf'
    );

} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Basically, I'm trying to merge two pdf files with the pdftk program. If I just write the same exact command to the cmd by hand, it works and the O:\test\123.pdf file is created. But when I execute the above PHP file, nothing happens (blank page, the file is not created).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can your PHP user access cmd.exe? You might find the tools at [Microsoft's Sysinternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/default.aspx) very useful; particularly the process monitor.

Comment: I think yes. Other commands do work. If I try exec('ipconfig -all'), for example, it works. I downloaded the process monitor and it seems that every process with pdftk gets executed correctly. There is just one process which says "buffer overflown" or something like that.

Comment: Can you confirm that if you open cmd.exe and run 'O:\test\pdftk.exe O:\test\outputs\OPP\out.pdf O:\test\outputs\OPP\out2.pdf cat output O:\test\123.pdf' that it works as expected?

Comment: Yes. It works as expected when I type it directly into shell.

Answer (score 1):

Try escaping the directory separator:

```
exec("O:\\test\\pdftk.exe O:\\test\\outputs\\OPP\\out.pdf O:\\test\\outputs\\OPP\\out2.pdf cat output O:\\test\\123.pdf");
```

Or even better, use single quotes instead:

```
exec('O:\test\pdftk.exe O:\test\outputs\OPP\out.pdf O:\test\outputs\OPP\out2.pdf cat output O:\test\123.pdf');
```

Comment: No. That doesn't work. I also tried shell_exec() which doesn't work as well.

Comment: @Richard: Even still, you will need to correctly escape the directory separator or use single quotes instead.  Have you made sure `exec` and `shell_exec` are enabled in your configuration?

Comment: @Richard Knop try something simpler like writing some text to a file with shell_exec then maybe something else is wrong and not with php configuration(that is if exec is enabled)

Comment: exec() is enabled. I tried exec('ipconfig -all'); and shell_exec('ipconfig - all'); and both worked.

Comment: @Richard: That would suggest there's a problem with your command.  Try passing an array to the second parameter of exec, then `print_r` that array afterwards.

Comment: But once gain, when I write the command to the cmd manually by hand, it works. So the command must be ok. Also the exec() is enabled because when I try other commands, they work.

Comment: @Richard: that doesn't make much sense - if there was an error with the command then it would be output.  Is the [author's PHP script](http://www.accesspdf.com/pdftk/#forge_fdf) of any use to you?  Other than that, I'm out of ideas - sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a project that allows PHP to obtain and interact dynamically with a real cmd terminal. Get it here: https://github.com/merlinthemagic/MTS

After downloading you would simply use the following code:

```
//if you prefer Powershell, replace 'cmd' with 'powershell'
$shellObj    = \MTS\Factories::getDevices()->getLocalHost()->getShell('cmd');

$strCmd1   = 'O:\\test\\pdftk.exe O:\\test\\outputs\\OPP\\out.pdf O:\\test\\outputs\\OPP\\out2.pdf cat output O:\\test\\123.pdf';
$return1   = $shellObj->exeCmd($strCmd1);
```

The return will give you the command return OR error from cmd, just as if you sat at the console. Furthermore, you can issue any command you like against the $shellObj, the environment is maintained throughout the life of the PHP script. So instead of bundling commands in a script file, just issue them one by one using the exeCmd() method, that way you can also handle the return and any exceptions.

Answer (score -1):

try Executing using the Admin Privileges for command prompt